# Scanner with GUI

Tags: java, swing, awt, jbutton

I want to make a program cipher using monoaphabetic cipher with java GUI.
But when I click the button to encrypt, the `textfield2` won't show the result and make the program crash.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   String en =  doEncryption(sc.next().toLowerCase());
   jTextField1.setT![enter image description here][1]ext(en);
   jTextField2.setText(doDecryption(en));
   sc.close();
}
```

Comment: When it "crashes" does some result or exception stacktrace is printed on the console?

Comment: List out all the details please, the actual exception string, noting the line that the exception is being thrown on, and the input you give for the scanner.....

Comment: Please provide the error message details/stack trace from the crash

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix event-driven GUI's with `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`. Seriously, just don't do this. This is what the GUI is for, and doing so without considering threading will render your program useless. Understand that `sc.next()` is a blocking call, a call that blocks the current thread until it completes, and that making this call on the Swing event thread will block the GUI, freezing it. But why even do this when you can get user input through your GUI, through one of your JTextFields or from a JTextArea for instance?

So instead of this:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   String en =  doEncryption(sc.next().toLowerCase());
   jTextField1.setText(en);
   jTextField2.setText(doDecryption(en));
   sc.close();
}
```

consider doing:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
   // Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

   // assuming entryTextArea is a JTextArea for user input:
   String en =  entryTextArea.getText().toLowerCase());
   jTextField1.setText(en);
   jTextField2.setText(doDecryption(en));
   // sc.close();
}
```